# QT/C++ Setting attributes to QObject by getting its name from variable

Tags: c++, qt

i have a bunch of lineEdits named like "e1", "e2", "e3" and so on.
i'd like to set same Style Sheet to all of them in a loop, not to code this

```
    ui->e1->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");    
    ui->e2->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
    ui->e3->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
    ui->e4->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
    ui->e5->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
    ui->e6->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
```

but something like this:

```
    for (z=1; z<7; z=z+1)
    {ui->e&z->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");}
```

maybe there is another way to set attributes to a bunch of similar objects? any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways you could do this.

## Arrays

If you're using the Qt Designer, this will be a pain to do.  But if not, just stuff all your `QLineEdit`s into a `std::array` and take it from there.

## Naming Conventions

Enforce a sequential naming convention for your `QLineEdit`s, e.g. `infoField1`, `infoField2`, etc.  Then just call `some_qobject.findChild(QString("infoField%1").arg(i))`.  This is error-prone, however.

## Stylesheets

I haven't actually used stylesheets with Qt, but it looks like you're using something CSS-like with it, right?  In that case, shouldn't you be able to just write one style and apply it to a particular set of (or even all) `QLineEdit`s?  I believe [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) would be a good place to look for that.

Comment: for some reasons i had to use Qt Disigner;( and the cause to chage the stylesheets of lineEdits is to make background of lineEdit red in case of wrong data typed into it. so this code was from button that clears background to "default" white color.

Comment: Stateful styles?  [You can do that with dynamic properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties).  An equivalent in HTML/CSS would be to use `.class-selectors`, but although that syntax exists for Qt stylesheets it means something different.

Answer (score 0):

got it.

used findChild method and loop for this.

```
    for (int e=1; e<7; e= e+1)
    {
      QLineEdit *field = findChild<QLineEdit*>("e" +QString::number(e));
      field->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
      field->setText("");
    }
```

works like a charm, nevertheless thanks @JesseTG for introduction of dynamic properties